# Selenium Grid: Error on hub log: Marking the node http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx as down: cannot reach the node for 2 tries

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

Trying to connect Windows VM (as a hub) and Windows Desktop machine or Windows VM (as a node) using Selenium grid. It continuously keeps on registering and unregistering
On configuring desktop as a node, getting message as “The node is registered to the hub and ready to use”, however after 2 minutes, hub console shows:
INFO [DefaultGridRegistry.add] - Registered a node http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
INFO [DefaultRemoteProxy.onEvent] - Marking the node http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx as down: cannot reach the node for 2 tries
INFO [DefaultRemoteProxy.onEvent] - Unregistering the node http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx because it's been down for 78019 milliseconds
WARN [DefaultGridRegistry.removeIfPresent] - Cleaning up stale test sessions on the unregistered node http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
INFO [DefaultGridRegistry.add] - Registered a node http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx

Tried using lower versions of selenium jar and using nodeconfig files too but no luck.
Looking for the rsolution, thanks in advance.